# How to select group independet from locale in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I always stumble about this problem in windows environments. From time to time I need to select something from a returned Object in Powershell and the only available Column is `Name`. For Example `Get-LocalGroup` the Users Group is named `Users` with locale english and `Benutzer` if locale is german. From my standpoint it seems impossible to create generalized Scripts or can I read from template or anything else depending on Locale?

I am really curious because I also walked over a few scripts which could be generalized but the english people sticked to the name column, which breaks the scripts in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, built-in identities like users and groups all have a specific security identifier (SID). For example, the local `BUILTIN\Users` group always has the SID `S-1-5-32-545`. In Powershell, you could use:

```
Get-LocalGroup -SID S-1-5-32-545

Name  Description                                                                                                
----  -----------                                                                                                
Users Users are prevented...
```

The full list of well-known SIDs can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers

---

Other localizations like folder paths usually have an english shell method for querying that will work like automatic environment variables `$env:USERPROFILE` or `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")`, but there is some variety depending on what you need.

Comment: I accept the answer, because it is correct and I actually knew already about it, but it is so inconvenient and human un-readable, that I never mesmerize it. Hard World if you know better standards. But thanks for the link, I might need it in future.